# Evaluating a generating function

Tags: generating-functions

$$\frac{x}{{{{(1 - x)}^6}}} = x\sum\limits_n^\infty  {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {n + 5}  \\
   5  \\
\end{array}} \right)} {x^n} = \sum\limits_n^\infty  {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {n + 5}  \\
   5  \\
\end{array}} \right)} {x^{n + 1}}$$

The conclusion is that the coefficient of $x^n$ is 
$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {n + 4}  \\
   5  \\
\end{array}} \right)$.

Can you explain where the $x$ (middle expression) came from?
And why the coefficient of $x^n$ is  $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {n + 4}  \\
   5  \\
\end{array}} \right)$? maybe it's a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The middle expression is the result of iterated use of the power rule. If you take the $n^\text{th}$ (formal) derivative of $\frac1{1-x}$, you end up with $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$ times some polynomial in $n$. If you then take the fifth derivative of the geometric series, then you can work out the coefficient to be $\binom{n+5}{5}$ but missing some terms; those terms come from that extra polynomial in $n$.

The reason you end up with $n+4$ instead of $n+5$ will be obvious if you are more careful about the indices of summation.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't mention that. It's because you have an $x$ in the numerator of the first expression. You could maybe be fancy and try to incorporate it into the series somehow but that seems a lot harder than the tactic of "ignore it for now and hope the problem disappears later". Since the problem *does* disappear later, you're fine :P